# if I pass "image/jpeg" in the toDataURL() I lost the quality?

Tags: html, canvas, jpeg, todataurl

I am trying to save html5 canvas data to server if I pass "image/jpeg" as the first argument in the toDataURL() method I lost the quality?

How can I keep the same quality on image png

Comment: You can specify your own image quality as the second parameter, don't you? `canvas.toDataURL(type,quality);`

Comment: I have a png image and I need to save it in jpeg image and I want to keep the quality of image , so I need to know the value of argument "quality"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define your own image quality use: `toDataURL( type , quality );`

```
toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1  ); // HQ
// 0.92 = FF default
toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.4); // LQ
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) :

> toDataURL(in optional DOMString type, in any ...args)     DOMString   Returns a data: URL containing a representation of the image in the format specified by type (defaults to PNG). The returned image is 96dpi.
>
> - If the height or width of the canvas is 0, "data:," representing the empty string, is returned.
> - If the type requested is not image/png, and the returned value starts with `data:image/png`, then the requested type is not supported. Chrome supports the image/webp type.
> - If the requested type is image/jpeg or image/webp, then **the second argument**, if it is between `0.0` and `1.0`, **is treated as indicating image quality**; if the second argument is anything else, the default value for image quality is used. Other arguments are ignored.

Comment: the second argument if equal to 1 , it means I keep the quality of image? is this work in chrome and firefox?

Comment: @LallouDaddou 1 = High, 0 = Low, like in Photoshop, it's the way to define a jpg image quality before being sent to imaging algorithms. and compression.